# Hard Drive Wiped Clean - TFS Thinks I Have the Latest

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to tell TFS that I really don't have the latest of any files on my hard drive? My hard drive was wiped clean and I have to do a `get specific` every time I get the latest files because TFS thinks I already have the latest of many solutions. The problem is that we have 100 solutions and I can never remember which ones I've already done a `get specific`. I want TFS to act like I have no files on my system so a normal `get latest` works from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do "tf workspace /delete *" all of your workspaces will be deleted and TFS will have no knowledge of which files you have.

You can also delete your workspaces in Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked well. A couple of tips: undo any pending changes so there are no orphaned check-outs, and delete any recently-retrieved source code from your hard drive (that way TFS and hard drive are in sync).

Comment: If you delete a workspace then any check-outs within it are automatically undone :)... but good advice.